# React functional component, how to pass attributes to an input element dynamically via an onChange event

Tags: reactjs

I have this code, I'm trying to pass the function `validateWhileInputing` to the input element, this function would perform an onChange event that would check the user input, and it would return two attributes, valid or invalid, according to the input.

```
const validateWhileInputing = (e) => {

  const onChange = (e) => validateWhileInputing(e)

  const input = e.target.value
  if (input === "") {
    return {
      valid: false,
      invalid: true
    }      
  } else {
    return {
      valid: true,
      invalid: false
    }
  }
}

const YeniTeklif = () => {

  return (
  <>
     <CInput {...validateWhileInputing(e)} placeholder = "1"/>           
     <CInput {...validateWhileInputing(e)} placeholder = "2"/>           
     <CInput {...validateWhileInputing(e)} placeholder = "3"/>           
  </>
  )
}

export default YeniTeklif
```

I could easily solve this issue using react setState hook. But I have many input fields and I don't want to declare a state hook for each input elements. I was wondering if I could do it dynamically?

Comment: Is your project restricting use of external libraries? If not, maybe have a look at [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) which has already solved this problem

Comment: I'll be sure to check out that library, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have some state setter to trigger component update. This state can either be in a parent component or in `CInput`. You don't have to create separate state setters for each input, one array with all validations is enough:

```js
const YeniTeklif = () => {  
  const [validations, setValidation] = useState(Array(3).fill(false));
  const validateWhileInputing = (e) => (i) => {
    const isEmpty = e.target.value === "";
    setValidation((validations) => {
      if (validations[i] !== isEmpty) {
        validations = validations.slice();
        validations[i] = isEmpty;
      }
      return validations;
    }
  return (
  <>
    {
      validations.map((validation, i) => {
        <CInput onChange={validateWhileInputing(i)} placeholder={i+1} />
      })
    }
                
  </>
  )
}

export default YeniTekli
```

But this causes all inputs to rerender even if only one of them is required to change. More efficient way would be to modify `CInput` so that it holds it's own validation status:

```js
const CInput = ({placeholder}) => {
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
  const validate = (e) => {
    const isValid = !!e.target.value;
    setValid(isValid);
  }
  return (
    <input onChange={validate} placeholder={placeholder} />
  )
}
```

You can also pass a custom validation function to the `CInput` and then use it in its handler:

```
const validate = (e) => {
    const isValid = validation(e.target.value);
    setValid(isValid);
  }
```